# Creativity use case scenario?

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-web-services, chef, kubernetes

i am a devops learner, just finished graduation actively looking for jobs in the field of DevOps.

I am learning many tools like GIT, Jenkins, Chef, Docker , Nagious, ELK, AWS, etc.

Can anyone link all the DevOps tools together and give me a scenario where and how a company uses these tools at different times?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is quite vague/generic.

People store their source code (or generally, files) in git; let Jenkins run jobs (like CI/CD pipelines), use Docker to put their software into well-defined containers, Nagios to monitor their systems, ELK to collect, store and visualize (mostly logging, event) data, AWS to host their stuff, and Chef to manage their configurations.

If you are studying that and learning about it, then you should have gotten that kind of information, really. The scenario in real world companies is simply to use those tools for what they are made, in different combinations as needed.

If you really have just gotten some deficient information from your college or wherever you studied those things, then get a book like The DevOps Handbook and give it a read. It should clear up how all of this would work together in the real world.

Comment: Sorry to say, but none of this is true if the question would be related to "mainframes" ... running an OS like "zOS" (with the "z" for "zero downtime"). Want to update your answer?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, I cannot relate your comment to the question or my answer at all. Did you intend to post it somewhere else?

Comment: DevOps also applies to mainframe ... while the question seems to be OS independent ... Though OPer might not even realize that there are still companies depending on them, such as banks, airlines, etc. Ever wondered why online banking never appears to be down? Or what it costs for such systems to be unavailable for, say, 1 second?

Comment: Seems like a solid answer to me. The vague question named some tools and sort of asked when they would be used. The question did ask for a "scenario," but still a decent answer, IMHO.